# sapui5 JSON model and display in xml

Tags: javascript, json, xml, odata, sapui5

I need help with setting JSON model into my main model. I have data stored in "http://localhost:9041/main-app-web/MyServiceName.svc/GetSurname?id=1&name='matt'&$format=json"

Now i want to set it into model, i'm trying

```
var oModelJs = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/main-app-web/MyServiceName.svc/GetSurname?id=1&name='matt'&$format=json");
this.getView().setModel(oModelJs, "model");
```

but it is giving me oData ={} ,
[image]
empty oData in debugger. How could i do that and then display my data eg. in table in xml?

Parameters stored in my json:

```
Id: "223",
MeterNumber: "1354-65498121"
```

Ty guys

Comment: What is the reason for not using an ODataModel? Are you getting some errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved this problem was adding correct items into `<Table items="{/d/results}">` and in cells  `<Text text="{id}" />` Ty for ur response santosh.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getView().setModel(oModelJs, "model");
```

The above line of code is not needed.

Next yo have to get the table ID and set the model to the table.

```
this.getView().byId("tableId").setModel(oModelJs);
```

Comment: And the way to display that is: https://pastebin.com/tbM4c6HN ?
I have problem with displaying. The way i'm using it in xml is right?

For test i'm using https://pastebin.com/h8y5rVTj .

Comment: In xml you have to a property items="{/}" and in the binding remove the '/' before the binding path